# Store a single value from ResultSet in a variable and use it on another page

Tags: jsp, resultset

In my code I want to store "password" which is 4th attribute in a table "register" to a variable from ResultSet, and keep it in a session and use it on another page.

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
try
{
String eml =  request.getParameter("email");
session.setAttribute("to",eml);
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","1234"     
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(" select * from register where email='"+eml+"' ");
while(rs.next())
**String psw = rs.getString(4);**
}
**session.setAttribute("pswd",psw);**
response.sendRedirect("sendProcess.jsp");
rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
}
catch(Exception e){}
%>
```

Comment: Please anybody correct my code or suggest a correct code for doing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad practice to make connection object in JSP page. See JSP page is generally considered to display Information. Try to send request to servlet and within servlet call another class containing your business logic code(which you inserted within JSP page). Then according to the response you get from your business logic store your result into session attribute and redirect from servlet to desired page.
And try to declare `String psw` outside the loop.

```
String psw=null;
while(rs.next())
{ 
psw = rs.getString(4);
}
session.setAttribute("pswd",psw);
```

Comment: Declaring "String psw" outside the loop worked. Thanks a lot !